# Wordpress - Conditional Custom Field Image

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am bringing in a custom field onto my Wordpress template page as follows, but would like to know of how I could display an image in its place if there is no custom field inserted...

```
<?php 
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail');
?>
```

UPDATE: kinda got this working like this:

```
 <?php $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true);
//Checking if anything exists for the custom field thumbnail id
if ($thumbnail_id) { ?>
 <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, '');?>
<?php } //if there is nothing for thumbnail then display
else { ?>
<img src="yoururlimage.com/image.jpg" /><?php } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: kinda got this working like this:

```
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id', true);
//Checking if anything exists for the custom field thumbnail id
if ($thumbnail_id) { ?>
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, '');?>
<?php } //if there is nothing for thumbnail then display
else { ?>
<img src="yoururlimage.com/image.jpg" /><?php } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail_id',     true)){
echo $thumbnail_id;}
else{echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail');}?>
```

Comment: hmm thanks, when I insert that code in place of what I have, it doesn't come up with the image s at all though...

Comment: it echos out the custom field value so use the `<img>` tags

Comment: This code snippet would be more helpful if you pointed out what change needed to be made.

Comment: ah, thanks... kinda got me on the right track. I had to mess with my original code a bit so that it worked.  Changes made above